# How to get the extend of tick labels, xlabel or ylabel?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

For an example code, I can get the extend of ax which is indicated by red vertical line. I also illustrated the extend of tick labels and and ylabel using yellow and blue by estimating a value.

**Is there a functional way to get the bounding box of ticklels, xlabel or ylabel?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.set_xlabel('x_label', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y_label', fontsize=14)

# method 1 to get the extend of ax
bbox1 = ax.get_position()
print(bbox1)
# method 2 to get the extend of ax
bbox2 = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.transFigure.inverted())
print(bbox2)
ax.text(bbox1.x0, 0.2, '|', transform=fig.transFigure, color='r', fontsize=30)
ax.text(0.07, 0.2, '|', transform=fig.transFigure, color='b', fontsize=30)
ax.text(0.03, 0.2, '|', transform=fig.transFigure, color='y', fontsize=30)
```

[image]

UPDATE:

using code below can get the xaixs tight_box and the figure tight_box

```
b1 = ax.xaxis.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).transformed(fig.transFigure.inverted())
b2 = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer()).transformed(fig.transFigure.inverted())
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I modifiied the question a bit, and updated some methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interprete the question as to ask for how to get the bounding box of the various text elements in the plot. Those bounding boxes are determined at draw time. Hence one would first need to draw the figure. Then

```
artist.get_window_extent()
```

returns the bounding box of the artist. The bounding box is in absolute pixel coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import IdentityTransform

def drawbb(bb, fig, **kwargs):
    r = plt.Rectangle((bb.x0, bb.y0), bb.width, bb.height, 
                      transform=IdentityTransform(), fill=False, **kwargs)
    fig.add_artist(r)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3, 2))
ax.set_xlabel('x_label', fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('y_label', fontsize=14)
fig.tight_layout()


fig.canvas.draw()

drawbb(ax.xaxis.label.get_window_extent(), fig, edgecolor="crimson")
drawbb(ax.yaxis.label.get_window_extent(), fig, edgecolor="indigo")
drawbb(ax.get_xticklabels()[3].get_window_extent(), fig, edgecolor="limegreen")

plt.show()
```

[image]